# How to pass filename(image file) as a whole parameter into code igniter class?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu

I'm using dynamic image resize on CodeIgniter. My standard URL is as follows:

http://example.com/img/800/600/imagename.jpg

In local with MAMP there is no problem but when I upload to remote Ubuntu server it gives an HTTP 404 error.

I realized that if I end up with a slash it works and recognizes imagename.jpg as a whole parameter. Otherwise period causes a problem.

http://example.com/img/800/600/imagename.jpg/

In routes.php:

```php
$route['img/(:num)/(:num)/(:any)'] = "image/dynamicresize/$1/$2/$3";
```

I use the following function

```php
function dynamicresize($w, $h, $filename) {
}
```

Why does that not work on remote server?

Comment: Please check your controller file name linux is case sensitive while loading file. First letter of your controller file name and class name should be capital